# Insert image in table and align text in center vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, align

I'd like to align my text in table with figures. The desire result is given by [image: Aligned text in table]

I tried and I obtained this code

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}       
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} c}
        \hline
        Nome                                   & Dim. & Range           & Ótimo & Sketchup em 2D \\ \hline
        %
        Sphere                                 & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1400 & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        %
        Rotated Bent Cigar                     & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1200 & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Discus                         & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1100 & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Schwefel                               & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -100  & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Schwefel                       & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 100   & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Katsuura                       & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 200   & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 2 (n=3,Unrotated) & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 800   & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 5                 & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 1100  & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 8 (n=5,Rotated)   & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 1400  & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

This code produces
[image]

Comment: In `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` you will not need to file. The question is: How to centering text in the table.

Comment: Replace the `p` column type with `m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly the only problem is that you were shifting the image too far, by the full height when you want less than half that, but I made a few less important changes as well

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  
    \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}    
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \hline
        Nome                                   & Dim. & Range           & Ótimo & Sketchup em 2D \\ \hline
        %
        Sphere                                 & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1400 & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        %
        Rotated Bent Cigar                     & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1200 & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Discus                         & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1100 & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Schwefel                               & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -100  & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Schwefel                       & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 100   & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Katsuura                       & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 200   & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 2 (n=3,Unrotated) & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 800   & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 5                 & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 1100  & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 8 (n=5,Rotated)   & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 1400  & \raisebox{-.4\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{sphere.png}}               \\[1cm] \hline
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip

    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried using this method to vertically center the text of a table that has two image columns. Text columns get vertically centered but row distance seems to have reduced. Now the images have no row distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

Images naturally build above the base line a little below the level of the minus `-` sign. That is why raising the images by `-\totalheight` is never accurate. Another simpler approach without using trial-and-error is to encapsulate the image in a tabular because tabulars are naturally vertically centered. A new command `\tabcell` can be used for this as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tabcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}\label{my-label}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}       
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} c}
        \hline
        Nome                                   & Dim. & Range           & Ótimo & Sketchup em 2D \\ \hline \noalign{\vskip2pt}
        Sphere                                 & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1400 & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        %
        Rotated Bent Cigar                     & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1200 & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Discus                         & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -1100 & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Schwefel                               & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & -100  & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Schwefel                       & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 100   & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Rotated Katsuura                       & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 200   & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 2 (n=3,Unrotated) & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 800   & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 5                 & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 1100  & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\
        Composition Function 8 (n=5,Rotated)   & 30   & $[-100, 100]^p$ & 1400  & \tabcell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=20mm]{sphere.png}}               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]